# What does this "+10 attack" mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranged-attack

I'm playing a level 5 Eladrin Ranger (I think it's a pre-gen) with 4e rules. On my character sheet under attacks it says:

> Longbow: +10 attack, 1d10+1 damage

What is the +10? Do I add it to my attack roll? Cause that'd be awesome, but adding 10 to every roll seems kind of OP. I know how to do the damage, I only want to know what I do with this +10. I can't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. The site accommodates reasonably-sized pics, so if it would be easier to show than tell, you can upload a photo of what you're trying to figure out. Also, *pre-gen* means *pre-generated*; that is, it means the character comes from somewhere else rather than you making it yourself as an original piece of work using the rulebooks. (Not trying to be condescending; just making sure we're talking about the same thing.) So where'd you find this character sheet? Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 10):

**That's your total attack modifier, which is added to your d20 roll.**

The Character Builder (and its associated character sheet viewer) automatically adds all relevant numbers for a power together and gives you the total, to allow for quick reference instead of having to add everything up manually every time. It can be customized to display values for a number of different weapons, if you have more than one applicable one available.

As a side note, +10 is a pretty standard attack bonus at level 5, it's certainly not OP.

Comment: Might even be a touch low.

Comment: Probably worth noting: at level 5, your average monster should have an AC of 19.  +10 to hit means you would have a 60% chance of hitting, on average, which is standard to slightly low.